# Improve a Join performance

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join

This query runs slowly:

```
SELECT UserAccountNumber, balance, username FROM users JOIN balances ON 
users.UserAccountNumber=balances.UserAccountNumber WHERE date < “2011-02-02”
```

What can i do to improve its performance?

I thought about using the user ID for the join instead of the userAccountNumber.
Appart form it, as far as i know, the JOIN and WHERE users.id = balances.idUser perform at the same speed...

So.. what else could i change to improve it?
Thanks.

Comment: We'll need more info on your schema. Are you using indexes and foreign keys?

Comment: What indicies do you have?  If you have both a `userId` and `userAccountNumber` in both `users` and `balances`, you haven't normalized your setup completely, which _could_ come back to bite you later (what happens if they no longer point to the same `user` record?).

Comment: I have the UserAccountNumber indexed. But. wouldn't it be faster to have another table with UserAccountNumber and ID and here only using the ID to make the JOIN? Thanks.

Comment: Which table is the column 'date' in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query itself looks OK to me, but make sure you have indexes on the `UserAccountNumber` columns (since they're involved in the join) and `date` (the column you're searching on).  If the database has to do a sequential scan of a lot of records, that'll be slow.  Using `EXPLAIN SELECT` may help you to understand how the database is actually performing the query.

Comment: Ok, so i will have to index also the date column. 
And... what about using and UNIXDATE saving the DATE field as an INT? Isn't it faster than comparing DATE fields?

Comment: Dates are probably already stored as integers internally, so I doubt it'd make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

If the tables are huge you might get some improvement using a temporary table rather then letting MySQL's optimiser sort it out for you.  It'll be a trade off for sure though.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tmp_balances`
(
  `UserAccountNumber` INT,
  `balance` INT,
  INDEX (`UserAccountNumber`)
) ENGINE=MEMORY
SELECT `UserAccountNumber`, `balance`
FROM balances
WHERE date < "2011-02-02";

SELECT `tmp_balances`.`UserAccountNumber`, 
    `tmp_balances`.`balance`, 
    `users`.`username`
FROM `tmp_balances` INNER JOIN users USING (`UserAccountNumber`);
```

Other then that (and it's a bit of a long-shot), I'd have to echo what the earlier commentors said about indexing.